# How to show html form with submit button and hidden input fields in flutter

Tags: android, html, forms, api, flutter

I have one API that returns html form with hidden input fields (the input field values are fetched from some other APIs), post method and submit button. I want to show that form button on a card of a list and when user clicks on submit button it should open another webpage. Could you please tell me if there is any possible way of doing this in Flutter/Android?
Is it possible to submit the request using any library and send the html response to an in-app browser? Please let me know if this can be achieved.

Comment: Hi @snj, do you have any sample code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried with flutter_html plugin and html plugin but no luck so far

Comment: Have you fount any solution? I am trying to implement like this,

Comment: Yes, I got workaround.  Please check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got one workaround for this.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_widget_from_html/flutter_widget_from_html.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart' as webview_flutter;

const kHtml = """
Foo bar.
<form action="https://the-url-with-post-method/post" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
The end.
""";

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text('issue 126')),
          body: HtmlWidget(
            kHtml,
            factoryBuilder: (c) => _CustomWidgetFactory(c),
          ),
        ),
      );
}

class _CustomWidgetFactory extends WidgetFactory {
  _CustomWidgetFactory(HtmlWidgetConfig config) : super(config);

  @override
  NodeMetadata parseLocalName(NodeMetadata meta, String localName) {
    if (localName != 'form') return super.parseLocalName(meta, localName);

    return lazySet(null,
        buildOp: BuildOp(
          onWidgets: (meta, _) => [
            Builder(
              builder: (context) => RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Submit this form."),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (_) => _FormSubmit(meta.domElement.outerHtml))),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}

class _FormSubmit extends StatelessWidget {
  final String html;

  _FormSubmit(String formHtml)
      : html = """<html>
<body onload="document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();">
  <p>Loading...</p>
  <div style="opacity: 0">$formHtml</div>
</body>
</html>""";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: webview_flutter.WebView(
          initialUrl: Uri.dataFromString(
            html,
            mimeType: 'text/html',
          ).toString(),
          javascriptMode: webview_flutter.JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        ),
      );
}
```

Comment: Hi, is there a workaround like for flutter-web as well?